# asyncsocket ipad doesn't connect to server

Tags: ios, ipad, networking, client-server, asyncsocket

My application times out while trying to connect to host. The timeout time is set to unlimited so I take it that the client is really just unable to connect at all.

I have an iPad app running asyncsockets and I'm trying to get it to connect to a server on my desktop also using asyncsockets. The iPad is specifically iOS 5 and is using GCD asyncsockets.

The server is being invoked through a NSRunLoop. It receives no form of connection from the client (none of breakpoints are caught like they are for telnet connections).

I'm able to telnet into the server from other machines just fine. I'm also able to connect the iPad client to host:google.com on port:80 just fine.

I've tried connecting the iPad to the server on ports 8080, 4500, and 50000 all to no success (they all work for telnet though).

I believe there is something in the server code causing this but I am not sure.

My server code is from a sample found here: http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2010/07/tweak-away/

My client code is modified HTTP client code from the sample GCD code supplied by the asyncsockets repository: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/blob/master/Examples/GCD/SimpleHTTPClient/Mobile/SimpleHTTPClient/SimpleHTTPClientAppDelegate.m

Here is my server code:

```
  - (id) init;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        debugServer = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        connectedClients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        running = false;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc;
{
    [self stop];
    [connectedClients release];
    [debugServer release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) startOnPort
{
    if (running) return;

    if (_port < 0 || _port > 65535)
        _port = 0;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![debugServer acceptOnPort:_port error:&error])
        return;

    NSLog(@"My Awesome Debug Server has started on port %hu", [debugServer localPort]);

    running = true;
}


- (void) stop;
{
    if (!running) return;

    [debugServer disconnect];
    for (AsyncSocket* socket in connectedClients)
        [socket disconnect]; 

    running = false;
}


- (void) setPort:(int)in_port{
    _port = in_port;
}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)socket didAcceptNewSocket:(AsyncSocket *)newSocket;
{
    [connectedClients addObject:newSocket];
}


- (void)onSocketDidDisconnect:(AsyncSocket *)socket;
{
    [connectedClients removeObject:socket];
}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)socket didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port;
{
    NSLog(@"Accepted client %@:%hu", host, port);

    NSData *welcomeData = [@"Welcome to my Awesome Debug Server\r\n\r\n" 
                           dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [socket writeData:welcomeData withTimeout:-1 tag:WelcomeMsgTag];

    [socket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:GenericMsgTag];
}


- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)socket didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag;
{
    NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    NSString *input = [tmp stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                       [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSLog(@"%@",input);

    if ([input isEqualToString:@"exit"])
    {
        NSData *byeData = [@"Bye!\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [socket writeData:byeData withTimeout:-1 tag:GenericMsgTag];
        [socket disconnectAfterWriting];
        return;
    }

    [socket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:GenericMsgTag];
}

@end
```

...and here is my client code:

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
    // AsyncSocket optionally uses the Lumberjack logging framework.
    // 
    // Lumberjack is a professional logging framework. It's extremely fast and flexible.
    // It also uses GCD, making it a great fit for GCDAsyncSocket.
    // 
    // As mentioned earlier, enabling logging in GCDAsyncSocket is entirely optional.
    // Doing so simply helps give you a deeper understanding of the inner workings of the library (if you care).
    // You can do so at the top of GCDAsyncSocket.m,
    // where you can also control things such as the log level,
    // and whether or not logging should be asynchronous (helps to improve speed, and
    // perfect for reducing interference with those pesky timing bugs in your code).
    // 
    // There is a massive amount of documentation on the Lumberjack project page:
    // https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack
    // 
    // But this one line is all you need to instruct Lumberjack to spit out log statements to the Xcode console.

    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

    // Create our GCDAsyncSocket instance.
    // 
    // Notice that we give it the normal delegate AND a delegate queue.
    // The socket will do all of its operations in a background queue,
    // and you can tell it which thread/queue to invoke your delegate on.
    // In this case, we're just saying invoke us on the main thread.
    // But you can see how trivial it would be to create your own queue,
    // and parallelize your networking processing code by having your
    // delegate methods invoked and run on background queues.

    asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    // Now we tell the ASYNCHRONOUS socket to connect.
    // 
    // Recall that GCDAsyncSocket is ... asynchronous.
    // This means when you tell the socket to connect, it will do so ... asynchronously.
    // After all, do you want your main thread to block on a slow network connection?
    // 
    // So what's with the BOOL return value, and error pointer?
    // These are for early detection of obvious problems, such as:
    // 
    // - The socket is already connected.
    // - You passed in an invalid parameter.
    // - The socket isn't configured properly.
    // 
    // The error message might be something like "Attempting to connect without a delegate. Set a delegate first."
    // 
    // When the asynchronous sockets connects, it will invoke the socket:didConnectToHost:port: delegate method.

    NSError *error = nil;

#if USE_SECURE_CONNECTION
    uint16_t port = 443; // HTTPS
#else
    uint16_t port = 8080;  // HTTP
#endif

    DDLogVerbose(@"port: %d\t host: %@",port,@"130.85.92.12");

    if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:@"130.85.92.12" onPort:port error:&error])
    {
        DDLogError(@"Unable to connect to due to invalid configuration: %@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        DDLogVerbose(@"Connecting...");
    }

#if USE_SECURE_CONNECTION

    // The connect method above is asynchronous.
    // At this point, the connection has been initiated, but hasn't completed.
    // When the connection is establish, our socket:didConnectToHost:port: delegate method will be invoked.
    // 
    // Now, for a secure connection we have to connect to the HTTPS server running on port 443.
    // The SSL/TLS protocol runs atop TCP, so after the connection is established we want to start the TLS handshake.
    // 
    // We already know this is what we want to do.
    // Wouldn't it be convenient if we could tell the socket to queue the security upgrade now instead of waiting?
    // Well in fact you can! This is part of the queued architecture of AsyncSocket.
    // 
    // After the connection has been established, AsyncSocket will look in it's queue for the next task.
    // There it will find, dequeue and execute our request to start the TLS security protocol.
    // 
    // The options passed to the startTLS method are fully documented in the GCDAsyncSocket header file.
    // The deusty server only has a development (self-signed) X.509 certificate.
    // So we tell it not to attempt to validate the cert (cause if it did it would fail).

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
                                                        forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain];

    [asyncSocket startTLS:options];

#endif
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"socket:didConnectToHost:%@ port:%hu", host, port);

    // HTTP is a really simple protocol.
    // 
    // If you don't already know all about it, this is one of the best resources I know (short and sweet):
    // http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/
    // 
    // We're just going to tell the server to send us the metadata (essentially) about a particular resource.
    // The server will send an http response, and then immediately close the connection.

    NSString *msg = @"iOS client connected\r\n\r\n";
    NSData *msgdata = [msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [asyncSocket writeData:msgdata withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];

    // Side Note:
    // 
    // The AsyncSocket family supports queued reads and writes.
    // 
    // This means that you don't have to wait for the socket to connect before issuing your read or write commands.
    // If you do so before the socket is connected, it will simply queue the requests,
    // and process them after the socket is connected.
    // Also, you can issue multiple write commands (or read commands) at a time.
    // You don't have to wait for one write operation to complete before sending another write command.
    // 
    // The whole point is to make YOUR code easier to write, easier to read, and easier to maintain.
    // Do networking stuff when it is easiest for you, or when it makes the most sense for you.
    // AsyncSocket adapts to your schedule, not the other way around.

#if READ_HEADER_LINE_BY_LINE

    // Now we tell the socket to read the first line of the http response header.
    // As per the http protocol, we know each header line is terminated with a CRLF (carriage return, line feed).

    [asyncSocket readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];
#else

    // Now we tell the socket to read the full header for the http response.
    // As per the http protocol, we know the header is terminated with two CRLF's (carriage return, line feed).

    [asyncSocket readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];

#endif
}

- (void)socketDidSecure:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock
{
    // This method will be called if USE_SECURE_CONNECTION is set

    DDLogVerbose(@"socketDidSecure:");
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"socket:didWriteDataWithTag:");
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"socket:didReadData:withTag:");

    NSString *httpResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",httpResponse);

#if READ_HEADER_LINE_BY_LINE

    DDLogInfo(@"Line httpResponse: %@", httpResponse);

    // As per the http protocol, we know the header is terminated with two CRLF's.
    // In other words, an empty line.

    if ([data length] == 2) // 2 bytes = CRLF
    {
        DDLogInfo(@"<done>");
    }
    else
    {
        // Read the next line of the header
        [asyncSocket readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];
    }

#else

    DDLogInfo(@"Full httpResponse: %@", httpResponse);

#endif

    [httpResponse release];
}

- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err
{
    // Since we requested HTTP/1.0, we expect the server to close the connection as soon as it has sent the response.

    DDLogVerbose(@"socketDidDisconnect:withError: \"%@\"", err);
}
```

I've looked around for answers but have had no success. I figured the best course of action would be to ask you all rather than wrack my brain trying to solve it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to connect to the local network differently. I was operating with a network that required a log in for local access but offered a "visitors" connection for wide area network access. The device (iPad) was automatically connecting as a "visitor" and I needed to log in manually.

So, if you aren't able to connect w/ this API, check out how your connecting to the network!